# How should I mount conduit to my wood-laped siding?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, conduit, nec

I was thinking about using superstrut to hang conduit on the side of the house, but hangers would be easier because siding is wood-lapped so it is not a flush surface.

I'm open to other options as well:

Questions:

- Does NEC code accept screwing a conduit hanger through its hole into a wooden wall (wood-lapped house siding), or are hangers only to be used for hanging?
- I have to run about 20' of conduit outside, how many feet between mounting points?

[image: Conduit Hanger]

Here is what the siding looks like (roughly, I found the picture online.  Mine is painted, but otherwise similar)

[image: wood-lapped siding]

Comment: That's Dutch Lap siding. Most of it is flat and flush, with just the small gaps where the lower piece goes under the upper piece. What's wrong with Superstrut? You don't have clapboards where the entire surface of each piece is at an angle. Also, is your run horizontal or vertical?

Comment: @FreeMan, the run is horizontal.  Superstrut is fine, I just wondered if hangers were legal since they are easy to screw in with one hole---but that might not be enough hold power.

Comment: @FreeMan, for superstrut, what type of screws do you use to affix the strut?  Anything special?

Comment: Other options - Are you able to run the cable through the building's roof/ceiling space instead?  Is there a soffit overhead - you could run the conduit through there too.  Both options are visually better than screwing something to the exterior cladding, and will be better-protected.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For EMT (anyway) the spacing is pretty clear - I can't recall if it's the same or different for other types, but it might well be the same.

Within 12" of each box. 10 feet maximum spacing (1 clamp per stick of conduit, minimum.) You can do more than the minimums without an issue. You can't do less than that. So a typical 20 foot run would need at least 3 (both ends and the middle), or go *wild* and use 4.

Despite being called "hangers" a random manufacturer or dealer page I visited indicated that the device was "[suitable for horizontal or vertical installation.](https://www.cesco.com/Thomas-Betts-T-B--6H1-B-Steel-City-6H1-B-3-4-In-Conduit-Pipe-Hanger-with-Bolt/p2144314)" To be persnickity you would verify that the manufacturer of the specific device you purchase says the same, (so that you are "using it according to its instructions or labelling") but that's likely universal.

I would use short hot-galvanized or stainless steel lag bolts. Length should be such that they don't go more than 1-1/4" into the studs, and I would put them on studs, by preference, rather than just siding, and I'd spend the dime or so on a washer as well. You could probably get away with less, if you wanted to. I prefer not to have to revisit work later when it rusts away or pulls out.

Comment: For the within 12" of each box, is a (raintight) screw-in-to-compression fitting screwed into the raintight hub atop of the load center considered one of the supports for vertical runs?  I have a panel from about 10 years ago that passed inspection but its nearest support is a superstrut mount that is almost 4' from the top of the panel.  The 2" screw-in rain-tight hub connection is pretty stable, it seems silly to put a superstrut just above the screw-in point.

Comment: Take a picture, and ask a new question with that picture. ;^) It's not uncommon for inspectors to miss a few things, or not feel that they are serious enough to worry about, and it's also not uncommon for inspectors to want things that are not actual code. Nobody fights them on the first kind, normally.

Answer (score 16):

Those hangers will stick out and potentially catch on clothing.

I would use saddles.

[image]

Comment: Worth mentioning that these hold just fine when the surface they are attaching to isn't totally flat or perpendicular. Lapped siding is a non-issue with these.

Comment: The one-hole version also works fine. Mostly a question of if you want the conduit spaced off the surface or tight to it. Catching on clothing would depend very much on where the conduit is *.vs.* people walking close to it, or not.